# Invalid syntax when running the function in jupyter notebook & get tensorboard is not defined when try to fit the model

Tags: python

Jupyter is throwing get_tensorboard not defined error, in my stack trace. Even though it has been defined.

```
def get_tensorboard(model_name)
    folder_name = f'{model_name} at {strftime("%H %M")}'
    dir_paths = os.path.join(LOG_DIR, folder_name)
    try:
        os.makedirs(dir_paths)
    except OSError as err:
        print(err.strerror)
    else:
        print('Successfully created directory')

    return TensorBoard(log_dir=dir_paths)
```

Stack trace -

```
 File "<ipython-input-143-2ab43f24c823>", line 1
    def get_tensorboard(model_name)

SyntaxError: invalid syntax


**Fit the Model**
%%time

model_1.fit(x_train_xs, y_train_xs, callbacks=[get_tensorboard('Model 1')])



NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<timed eval> in <module>

NameError: name 'get_tensorboard' is not defined
```

Comment: please [edit] your question to clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. as it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. see the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if that is what is causing this error, but in your question, you are missing a `:` after the Line: `def get_tensorboard(model_name)`. If you use any other IDE it would tell you, that you are missing a colon there. Maybe this happened while writing the question, but you should check that in your code

So instead of `def get_tensorboard(model_name)` it should be: 
`def get_tensorboard(model_name):`